# Equivalence of Brownian bridge and Brownian motion plus drift

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, brownian-motion

So the Brownian bridge is a Wiener process conditioned on fixed endpoints, i.e. $$B_t = \{W_t | W_0 =0, W_T = a\}$$

Is the analysis of the brownian bridge equivalent to the diffusion process with standard noise and a drift so that $\mathbb{E}[X_T] = a$? I.e.
$$dX_t = \frac{a}{T} dt + dW_t$$

I read that $W(t) + at$ is equivalent in law to the Brownian bridge that starts at $0$ and ends at $a$, but I'm not sure what this implies.

Comment: The SDE you have written won't give you a Brownian Bridge.

Comment: @rubikscube09 right, there's no condition that it $X_T = a$, but this is the expectation - wondering if this somehow implies equivalence in law